# What is a database closure?

Tags: sql, database, closures

I came across this term called database closure.

I tried to look for it and what exactly it means but I have not found any simple explanation.

Can someone please explain what the concept of closure is and specifically what is a database closure, if it is good /bad, how it can be used or avoided ?

Also seems like there is in general a closure term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29 which relates to binding of variables to function. Is a database closure related to this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you come across the term?

Comment: Providing context would be useful. If this was on the web, provide a link to the page where you saw this term. If it was somewhere else, specify where and give a few relevant sentences before and after.

Comment: http://blog.ttechnic.com/2010/10/database-closure-and-candidate-key.html . More imp, I want to understand the concept in general, and how it related to a database rather than what context it means in the link

Comment: Closure can mean a lot of things in a lot of contexts. Without that context its hard to answer.

Comment: Thnx Johan, I have already accepted an answer, but to answer your question, Sure it might mean a lot of things  so does word performance can mean a lot in different situations, but in general sense it does mean getting things done faster or getting more things done .. What idea should come to mind when I hear closure .. does it mean  "completeness"/"exhaustive" ? .. can you give some example of different contexts you are talking about, would love to hear more perspective.

Comment: My first thought was the [Closed World Assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_world_assumption).

Answer (score 15):

Closure is actually a relatively simple concept. When designing databases we want to know that our database tables have as little redundancy as possible. This means making sure that we can have as little relationships between sets (or tables) as possible.

An example:

If we have two sets X and Y (which you can think of as two tables called X and Y) and they have a relationship with each other as so:
X -> Y (Read this as Y is dependent on X)

And we have another set Z which is dependent on Y:
Y -> Z (also read as Y determines Z)

To find the closure we find the minimum number of tables that we can reach all relationships with. In this case all we need is X.

So now, when we design our database we know that we only have to have a relationship from X, and Z and Y can actually be derived from X. We can therefore make sure there are no extra relationships in our database which cause redundancy.

If you want to read more, closure is a part of a topic called normalisation.

Comment: Did you mean to say `Y -> Z` instead of `Z -> Y`?

Comment: This answer is misleading. In the case presented, the closure is not X, "the minimum number of tables that we can reach all relationships with"—this is getting at the definition of a key. Given the functional dependencies X → Y and Y → Z, the closure of {X} is {X, Y, Z}. In other words, {X} → {X, Y, Z}. Because the closure of X contains all attributes/relations, X makes for a good key.

Answer (score 2):

Closure is mentioned in database theory / set theory discussions -- as in, Dr. Codd / design & normalization kind of stuff.  It has to do with finding the minimally representational elements of sets (i.e., without redundancy, etc.).  I tried reading-up on it a long time ago, but my eyes went crossed, and I got a really bad headache.

If you want to read a decent summary of closure, here is one: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/354/jpei/slides/ClosureDecomposition.pdf

Comment: thnx user542398, atleast there is some documentation now.I agree to getting a bad headache. I will try to look at it again on a good day. Can someone explain in English? Btw I am not accepting this hoping that someone would come and explain this in easier way.

Answer (score 2):

The closure is essentially the full set of attributes that can be determined from a set of known attributes, for a given database, using its functional dependencies.

Formal math definition:

> Given a set of functional dependencies, F, and a set of attributes X. The closure is defined to be the set of attributes Y such that X -> Y follows from F.

Algorithm definition:

> ```
> Closure(X, F)
> 1  INITIALIZE V:= X
> 2  WHILE there is a Y -> Z in F such that:
>    - Y is contained in V and
>    - Z is not contained in V
> 3       DO add Z to V
> 4  RETURN V
> ```

It can be shown that the two definition coincide.

A database closure might refer to the closure of all of the database attributes. According to the definitions above, this closure would be the set of all attributes of the database itself.

The closure (computer science) term that you linked to is not related to closure in databases but the [mathematical closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) is.

For a better understanding of functional dependencies and a simple example for closure in databases I suggest reading [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency#Closure_of_a_set_of_attributes).

Answer (score 1):

All operations are performed on an entire relation and result in an entire relation, a concept known as closure. And that is one of relational database systems characteristics

Answer (score 0):

If we are referring to Closure in the Functional Dependency sense (relating to database design),

[The closure of a set F of functional dependencies is the set of all functional dependencies logically implied by F.](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter6/node12.html)

The minimal representation of sets is referred to as the [canonical cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_cover): the irreducible set of FD's that describe the closure.