# Is the meaning of the word closure in database what I'm talking about?

Tags: database, computer-science

Based on the statement

> Given a set F, formally, the set of all dependencies that include F as
> well as all dependencies that can be inferred from F is called the
> closure of F, denoted by F+

It appears that 'closure' signifies the set of all attributes that can be inferred through functional dependency.

**From my research**

In mathematics, 'closure' refers to a structure that is 'closed' under a certain operation, meaning that the outcome always remains within the same set under a specific mathematical operation or rule.

For instance, the sum of two integers always results in an integer, indicating that the operation is 'closed' within the set of integers.

Consequently, in this context, the set of integers is considered a closure under the operation of addition.

When extending this mathematical concept of closure to databases, the closure of a specific set F is the set where all elements satisfy a particular operation (in this case, functional dependency).

This implies that all elements of the set follow the rule of functional dependency within this closure.

So, is it correct to say that the term 'closure', borrowing from the mathematical concept, is used to depict the set where all elements adhere to the functional dependency rule, when examining this concept within the context of databases?

I'm a non-native English speaker and there are certain concepts that are challenging for me to understand.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I think you're thinking too hard.  The fact that two different fields, even related fields, use the same word doesn't mean they have the exact same meaning.  Typically, "closure" implies "F and everything that you can produce using F".  But what this means within any particular field, or even any particular textbook is up to that field or textbook.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you for your explanation.
I had difficulty associating the word "closure" with that concept. I was curious as to why databases use the term "closure" to convey this specific meaning.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324375/what-is-a-database-closure#:~:text=The%20closure%20is%20essentially%20the,a%20set%20of%20attributes%20X.  ??